# Bash - Parameters per couple with while

Tags: bash, while-loop, parameters

I want to make a Bash script with unlimited parameters.

**Example**:

```
sh example.sh data1 data2 data3 data4 data5 data6 dataN
```

And I want to get that parameters two by two. I tried with `do-while`:

```
while (( "$#" )); do 
  echo $1 $2
  shift 
done
```

But the last is always alone:

```
data1 data2
data2 data3
data3 data4
data4 data5
data5 data6
data6
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to shift two arguments, not just one; `shift` with no arguments is the same as `shift 1`.

```
while (( $# )); do
  echo "$1" "$2"
  shift 2
done
```